# Is there a function in Wireshark which I can use to decode packets in a memory buffer rather than a capture file?

Tags: c, network-protocols, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I have been reading the docs that come with Wireshark along with analyzing the source to figure out if there is a function or collection of functions in Wireshark which would allow me to pass a buffer containing capture data (rather than using an external file).

I asked [this question](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/201106/msg00041.html) on the Wireshark-dev list as well, but had no responses.

As far as I understand, you tell Wireshark where to look for packets (in terms of a file, pipe or socket) and it tells you whenever it's got a packet from that stream, so my gut feeling is that there isn't a way to pass a pointer to a buffer containing capture data and have Wireshark parse whatever it can find there.

However, I am by no means an expert on the internals of Wireshark, so I am looking to SO to help me figure out a definitive answer. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at `libpcap` sources, rather than `wireshark`. Namely, `pcap_open_offline()`. It should be easy to modify for looking at a memory block. Having said that, writing a temporary file is simple and easy and it's not clear why one should avoid it.

Comment: @n.m. Will look at `libpcap`. Thank you for the recommendation. However, I am trying to use Wireshark's dissectors to get at the information in those packets, so I do not know how much mileage I would get out of `libpcap`. In any case, my quest is to find a more definitive answer as to whether it is possible to use a memory buffer. The decision will depend on if it is possible and at what cost.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new `tvbuff_t` as `TVBUFF_REAL_DATA` and providing your memory region as the `data` parameter?

```
tvbuff_t *tvb = tvb_new_real_data(mem_buffer_ptr, mem_buf_length, mem_buf_length);
//mem_buffer_ptr is your memory buffer
//mem_buf_length is the number of bytes in your buffer
```

Wireshark historically does not play well with other applications, so whether this will work or not is questionable, especially if you think your data may change while it is being dissected. Is it not possible to write out a temporary file?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I haven't tried that but I'll give it a shot. My task right now is to figure out if there is some way. Evaluation of whether that's a good way is something to tackle later.